# Why does `node` pin versions of `npm` to each release?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, nvm

Some questions and answers hint there is an answer, but I don't think I see an answer in the forest.

I turned to `brew` to move away from `nvm` due to how my IDE loads the `$PATH` from the launcher. It seemed that it would not find the installed version of `node` or `npm` from the `.nvm` directory. When loaded from `/usr/local/bin` the IDE worked fine. Add that `brew` has an `nvm`-lite feature with `brew link --force [version]`.

However, what `brew` does not do is managed `npm` (at least very well). There is some discussion of this on the `brew` boards, but only that the suggestion that `brew` does not need to manage `npm`.

Thusly, `brew install node` gives me `node 7.7.2` and `npm 4.1.2`. All good.

But `brew unlink node && brew link node@6` gives me `node 6.10.0` and leaves `npm 4.1.2`. Whereas [nodejs.org suggests `npm 3.10.10`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) is the version of `npm` one should use.

Now, *if `node` pins a version of `npm` for a reason, and assuming a good reason, what is the reason?* I can't find anything. No one is talking about this connection. It might be my Google Fu, but what I have found suggests that a) no one knows, or b) the version of `npm` you use doesn't matter. The reasoning for the latter seems dubious: why bother pinning a version of `npm` to `node` if it didn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I was looking for an explicit statement from nodejs or npmjs about the "pinning" of an `npm` version to a `node` version/release.

Barring an explicit statement, I *could* read between the lines on npmjs: the pinning is simply a convenience for the user.

> Node comes with npm installed so you should have a version of npm. However, npm gets updated more frequently than Node does, so you'll want to make sure it's the latest version.

It then proceeds to tell the reader, run `npm install npm@latest -g`.

> Test: Run `npm -v`. The version should be higher than 2.1.8.

### Reading Between the Lines

Simply put, installing `node` gives you a version of `npm` at the time of the `node` release. npmjs suggests updating `npm` at *your* convenience.

So running `node` v6.10.10 with `npm` v4.1.2 should not be a problem. At least not a documented problem.